# VB.NET - Data not sending until the stream is closed

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a program that sends the client's screen to the server on load but the data doesn't send until the datastream is closed in the client program. I know flush is supposed to send the data but there is no difference when there is and when there isn't flush in the program.

Here is the main server code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Public Class Form1
    Dim encodeType As ImageFormat = ImageFormat.Bmp
    Dim decodingString As String = String.Empty
    Dim encodingTypeString = "data:image/bmp;base64"
    Public Function base64c(ByVal base64code As String) As Image
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64code)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
        Return Image.FromStream(ms, True)
    End Function
    Private Server As TCPControl
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Server = New TCPControl
        AddHandler Server.MessageReceived, AddressOf OnLineReceived
    End Sub


    Private Delegate Sub UpdateDesktopDelegate(Img As PictureBox, base64 As String)
    ' update image
    Private Sub OnLineReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)
        Desktop.Image = base64c(Data)
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Server.IsListening = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

The TCPControl server code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Public Class TCPControl
    Public Event MessageReceived(sender As TCPControl, Data As String)
    'Config
    Public ServerIp As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.254.14")
    Public ServerPort As Integer = 64555
    Public Server As TcpListener

    Private CommThread As Thread
    Public IsListening As Boolean = True
    'Clients
    Private Client As TcpClient
    Private ClientData As StreamReader

    Public Sub New()
        Server = New TcpListener(ServerIp, ServerPort)
        Server.Start()
        CommThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        CommThread.Start()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Listening()
        ' create listener loop
        Do Until IsListening = False
            ' accept incoming connections
            If Server.Pending = True Then
                Client = Server.AcceptTcpClient
                ClientData = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream)
            End If
            ' raise event for incoming messages
            Try
                RaiseEvent MessageReceived(Me, ClientData.ReadLine)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
            Thread.Sleep(300)
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

The main client code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
Public Class Form1
    Private Client As TCPControl
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Client = New TCPControl("192.168.254.14", 64555)
        Do Until False
            If Client.Client.Connected = True Then
                Dim bounds As Rectangle
                Dim screenshot As System.Drawing.Bitmap
                Dim newimg As System.Drawing.Bitmap
                Dim graph As Graphics
                bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
                bounds.Size = New Size(1920, 1080)
                screenshot = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(2600, 1330, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                graph = Graphics.FromImage(screenshot)
                graph.CopyFromScreen(bounds.X, bounds.Y, 0, 0, bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
                Using ms As New MemoryStream()
                    newimg = New Bitmap(screenshot, New Size(960, 540))
                    newimg.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp)
                    Dim imageBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
                    Client.Send(Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes))
                End Using
                Thread.Sleep(333)
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If Client.Client.Connected = True Then
            Client.DataStream.Close()
            Client.Client.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the client TCPControl code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.IO
Public Class TCPControl
    Public Client As TcpClient
    Public DataStream As StreamWriter

    Public Sub New(Host As String, Port As Integer)
        ' client
        Client = New TcpClient(Host, Port)
        DataStream = New StreamWriter(Client.GetStream)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Send(Data)
        DataStream.Write(Data)
        DataStream.Flush()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have been trying to solve this problem for hours now and posting on this website was my last resort. If any code is unorganized or is not as it should be then it is because I haven't focused on checking my code yet.

Comment: You'll have to rewrite this one from scratch. If you want to use Windows Forms as framework, you cannot use it as it was a Console application. For example `Do Until False` in Form.Load is a no go. Also, you don't need to use a Base64String to send images. The NetworkStream returned by `Client.GetStream()` writes Bytes. It also has asynchronous write support. On the server side, see [TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient). You're not disposing of the Bitmaps you create in a close loop → OutOfMemory.

Comment: If you don't get a OutOfMemory exception in due time, *something else* will close a Form that *doesn't pump*. Events and Timers can be your friends.